# Joining the two audio files in node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, audio

I am developing a web page , where a user will select two audio files and the app will join the two audio files and make it as a single output audio file. I am using nodejs in back end and angularjs in client side. How can I achieve this requirement? I went through many libraries nothing suits it.

Comment: ok with using `ffmpeg` in back-end?

Answer (score 5):

I'm looking at a similar use-case at the moment. The libraries aren't great as most need a big program to be installed in your server environment. Examples are:

- [sox-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sox-audio): Which should be ok as long as you don't need iterative (variable number of files) concatenation. But this requires installation of [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage).
- [audio-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audioconcat): A wrapper for [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), but also needs installation of ffmpeg.

Or of you don't need the output audio to be seekable, you could simply do it with streams. Concept:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('outputAudio.mp3'); // Or whatever you want to call it    

// Input files should be an array of the paths to the audio files you want to stitch
recursiveStreamWriter(inputFiles) {
    if(inputFiles.length == 0) {
        console.log('Done!')
        return;
    }

    let nextFile = inputFiles.shift(); 
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(nextFile);

    readStream.pipe(writeStream, {end: false});
    readStream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Finished streaming an audio file');
        recursiveStreamWriter(inputFiles);
    });
}
```

This works and the transitions are fine, but audio players struggle to seek the audio. A decent full example can be found [here](https://blog.ragingflame.co.za/2013/5/31/using-nodejs-to-join-audio-files) of the recursive stream method.

Answer (score 2):

As an example I am combining Iphone ringtone with Nokia ringtone and piping the streamed readers to a write stream.

```js
//Created two reader streams 
let readerstream1 = fs.createReadStream('iphone-6.mp3');       
let readerstream2 = fs.createReadStream('Nokia.mp3');

// Created a write stream
let writestream = fs.createWriteStream('NewRingtone.mp3');

//just pipe one after the other 
readerstream1.pipe(writestream);       
readerstream2.pipe(writestream);
```